# Align text left and right

Tags: html, css

I am reading data from a json DB and displaying it within a div. the only problem is im struggling with the layout I have the following headings.

I would like it to look like the following.(The dots are just to align everything space bar doesn't affect the position of a work)

***Sites Offline***...........................................................................................                                                ***Time Offline***

Test site 1.................................................................................................      .   .3 hours

please see what i have done below.

```
function CheckSitesDownTime(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'OfflineSites.json',
            dataType: 'json',
           type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $(data.SitesOffline1).each(function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value.time);
                        var para = document.createElement("h6");
var time = document.createTextNode(value.time);
para.appendChild(time);
para.className = "text-right";
console.log(para);
console.log("end");
document.getElementById("monitor-panel").appendChild(para);
                  });

            }
       });}

function CheckSites(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'OfflineSites.json',
            dataType: 'json',
           type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $(data.SitesOffline).each(function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value.name);
                        var para = document.createElement("h6");
var t = document.createTextNode(value.name);
para.appendChild(t);
para.
console.log(para);
console.log("end");
document.getElementById("monitor-panel").appendChild(para);
                  });
            }
       });}
```

The above code results in the following layout

***Sites Offline***................................................................................................***Time Offline***

Test site 1......................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................                                         ....................3 hours

i think i need to append them together at the same time so something like this

```
para.className = "style="text-align:left";
para.appendChild(Name);
para.appendChild ("<span")
para.className = "style="float:right;";
para.appendChild (Time)
para.appendChild ("</span>")
```

apologies for the poor quality code, started coding in HTML,CSS 2 days ago so still learning.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something quite useful in css nowdays called Flex box. 
You can read more in detail here. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You get the above result cause of the float.

Take this as example.

```css
.container{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span>Element 1</span>
<span>Element 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , was a big help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use display as grid for aligning items:

```css
   .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 3%;
    }

    .grid-container>div {
        background-color: grey;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .item1 {
        grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
    }

    .item0 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

    <div class="item1">Left</div>

    <div class="item0">Right</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [Vasilis's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53018084/209067) answer with the leading dots in CSS.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 20em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row span:not(.dots) {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.row .dots {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.row .dots::before {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  content: " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span>Element 1</span>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <span>Value 1</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span>Element 2</span>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <span>Value 2</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span>Element 3</span>
  <span class="dots"></span>
  <span>Value 3</span>
  </div
```

Comment: Thanks, the dots where just to justify the spaces as stacks overflow doesn't acknowledge spaces. still super cool how you did it tho, actually helped me with something else.